# How do I access libraries other than the Cocoa Storyboard library in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When I am on the storyboard in Xcode, I can only access the Cocoa Storyboard library classes. However, when I open the app, I see classes like address books and other GUI objects like beveled buttons and combo boxes. How do I access it for the storyboard? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those other objects are not part of UIKit and so can't be added to your storyboard or your app. When you're editing code then XCode doesn't really know (or has a bug!) that you are doing an iOS project so it shows you AppKit (OS X) widgets in the object browser as well.

Comment: Sweet that's what I thought. Thanks

Comment: If this has answered your question you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark. This increases the chance of people helping you in the future.